# Mutex: Wondering why UnauthorizedAccessException is not thrown as expected

Tags: c#, mutex

My application deals with different global [Mutexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx). The following simplified method checks, if a Mutex with a specific name already exists.

```
static bool MutexAlreadyExists(string mutexName)
{
    try
    {
        Mutex mutex;
        // should throw an UnauthorizedAccessException, if the mutex was acquired/owned by a different user
        bool exists = Mutex.TryOpenExisting(mutexName, out mutex);
        mutex?.Dispose();
        return exists;
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        // The mutex does exist, but we are not authorized to open it, because an other user owns it
        throw;
    }
    ...
}
```

**Scenario as expected:**
Assume *User A* is logged in onto a Windows 7 machine, starts the application and acquires the mutex *Global\MyApp_status* with success. Now *User B* loggs in and does the same without success. The `UnauthorizedAccessException` gets thrown as expected!

**Scenario as NOT expected:**
Assume *User A* is logged in onto a Windows 7 machine, starts the application and acquires the mutex *Global\MyApp_status* with success. Now *User A* executes the application as *User B* (hold SHIFT + right-click + Run as different User). The `UnauthorizedAccessException` gets NOT thrown.

**Question:** Why does the application not throw the exception in the second scenario hence the mutex is owned by a different user?

Comment: It has to do with how the `Mutex.TryOpenExisting` is implemented. How does it work when the same user(User A) Opens the application twice? Does it allow him to open? Can you debug and see what identity TryOpenExisting identifis if `RunAs` is  used for UserB?

Comment: @CarbineCoder: The same user is allowed to open the mutex twice. The Identity property is `null`.

Comment: Is Identity is what you are using it to constraint the mutex allocation? If so why null is allowed and given permission?

Comment: The primary token is still User A, even though the impersonation token is User B. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve with the mutex?

Comment: @Luaan Thank you for the explanation. The mutexes represent different states between starting and closing instances of the application.

Comment: @CarbineCoder I do not use and do not want to use any identity. The operating system/.NET class handles mutexes and their permissions.

Comment: So you want to make sure that different users on the machine can use the application simultaneously, but need to be coördinated?

Comment: @Luaan No, the app is a singleton, but starting and closing can happen simultanously. The question only focusses on the exception not beeing thrown in the second scenario. Also my provided code is highly simplified to really concentrate onto my question.

Comment: So  the `UnauthorizedAccessException` doesn't really matter at all, does it? You only really care about whether the mutex exists or not.

Comment: @Luaan Please focus on my question, I was just wondering about the described behaviour ;-)

Comment: @ChristianSt. Did you get to the bottom of that issue. I have the same scenario on Windows10/Server 2016 and I can figure why the impersonation scenario doesn't work.